# drop down value should not be display if select on any drop down-J query

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to make subject add or do not add type web-application. when user select a subject on 1st dropdown it should not be displayed on second dropdown and in the first dropdown  there should be a button (-) on side to remove selected  subject. Can anyone tell me how to do it in Jquery.

CODE

```
    <?php
//index.php

$connect = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=testing4", "root", "Lomass");
function fill_unit_select_box($connect)
{ 
 $output = '';
 $query = "SELECT * FROM tbl_unit";
 $statement = $connect->prepare($query);
 $statement->execute();
 $result = $statement->fetchAll();
 foreach($result as $row)
 {
  $output .= '<option value="'.$row["unit_name"].'">'.$row["unit_name"].'</option>';
 }
 return $output;
}

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Add Subjects</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <br />
  <div class="container">
   <h3 align="center">Add Subjects</h3>
   <br />
   <h4 align="center">Enter Item Details</h4>
   <br />
   <form method="post" id="insert_form">
    <div class="table-repsonsive">
     <span id="error"></span>
     <table class="table table-bordered" id="item_table">
      <tr>
       <th>Select Subjects</th>
       <th><button type="button" name="add" class="btn btn-success btn-sm add"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span></button></th>
      </tr>
     </table>
<!--     <div align="center">
      <input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-info" value="Insert" />
     </div>-->
    </div>
   </form>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

 $(document).on('click', '.add', function(){
  var html = '';
  html += '<tr>';
  html += '<td><select name="item_unit[]" class="form-control item_unit"><option value="">Select Subject</option><?php echo fill_unit_select_box($connect); ?></select></td>';
  html += '<td><button type="button" name="remove" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm remove"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></span></button></td></tr>';
  $('#item_table').append(html);
 });

 $(document).on('click', '.remove', function(){
  $(this).closest('tr').remove();
 });

 $('#insert_form').on('submit', function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  var error = '';
  $('.item_name').each(function(){
   var count = 1;
   if($(this).val() == '')
   {
    error += "<p>Enter Item Name at "+count+" Row</p>";
    return false;
   }
   count = count + 1;
  });

  $('.item_quantity').each(function(){
   var count = 1;
   if($(this).val() == '')
   {
    error += "<p>Enter Item Quantity at "+count+" Row</p>";
    return false;
   }
   count = count + 1;
  });

  $('.item_unit').each(function(){
   var count = 1;
   if($(this).val() == '')
   {
    error += "<p>Select Unit at "+count+" Row</p>";
    return false;
   }
   count = count + 1;
  });
  var form_data = $(this).serialize();
  if(error == '')
  {
   $.ajax({
    url:"insert.php",
    method:"POST",
    data:form_data,
    success:function(data)
    {
     if(data == 'ok')
     {
      $('#item_table').find("tr:gt(0)").remove();
      $('#error').html('<div class="alert alert-success">Item Details Saved</div>');
     }
    }
   });
  }
  else
  {
   $('#error').html('<div class="alert alert-danger">'+error+'</div>');
  }
 });

});
</script>
```

Here is the problem:

[see thee problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0X1Dr.png)

Comment: You need to add some code to explain the issue better. Can you share a jsfiddle or plunk URL to solve the above issue?

Comment: Please read [ask] and create a [mcve] - You need to [edit] the question, include the relevant parts of the code and explain what's wrong with it

Comment: i do not know how to write code in jquery for this requirment. I am in learning

Comment: what i need is 1st dropdown is selected as Math and i do not want to show math in 2nd dropdown. Thats the problem-> selected value should not be display in dropdown.

Comment: Are you using "Select" input or a "dropdown" navigation?

Comment: select....i have edited and submitted a code

Comment: Well, you can run the code snippet below. I wrote it out so you could see it function.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#firstSelect' ).change(function(){
  var firstValue=$('#firstSelect').val();
  var subjects=['Select Subject', 'Maths', 'History', 'Computer Science'];
  var secondSelect = '<select name="whatever">';
  for (var i=0; i<subjects.length; i++)
  {
    if (firstValue!=subjects[i])
       {
         secondSelect += '<option value="' + subjects[i] + '">' + subjects[i] + '</option>';
       }
   }
  secondSelect += '</select>';
  document.getElementById('secondSelectDiv').innerHTML= secondSelect;
});
```

There are many ways to do this. To use the method above, create the first dropdown or select. Next to it make an empty div with id of "secondSelectDiv". You don't really need to show the second select when the page loads because you don't know what the values should be. On change of the first select, create the second select, omitting the value of the first as an option. Once the select HTML is made, just put it in the empty div. This has an added benifit that if you just change the first select, the second will automatically update... no need for the minus button. You can also follow the same process using createElement if you want to create nodes. Be aware of case sensitivity on comparison of subjects. Subject values must match exactly in first select and second select/dropdown.

```js
$('#firstSelect' ).change(function(){
      var firstValue=$('#firstSelect').val();
      var subjects=['Select Subject', 'Maths', 'History', 'Computer Science'];
      var secondSelect = '<select name="whatever">';
      for (var i=0; i<subjects.length; i++)
      {
        if (firstValue!=subjects[i])
           {
             secondSelect += '<option value="' + subjects[i] + '">' + subjects[i] + '</option>';
           }
       }
      secondSelect += '</select>';
      document.getElementById('secondSelectDiv').innerHTML= secondSelect;
    });
```

```css
#firstSelect, #secondSelectDiv{
display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="firstSelect">
<option value="Select Subject">Select Subject</option>
<option value="Maths">Maths</option>
<option value="History">History</option>
<option value="Computer Science">Computer Science</option>
</select>
<div id="secondSelectDiv">
</div>
```

Comment: anyone Please hlp me

Comment: This is creation it own dropdown next. this is not what i want. see the edited post